# Connecting to SQL Server 2005 on another domain through VPN connection

Tags: sql-server-2005, vpn

I have SQL Server 2005 dev installed on my machine.

Using `SQL Server Management Studio`: how can I connect to a SQL Server on another domain?

Please note that the computer has to be VPN'ed into the domain I am connecting to.

Thanks,
Voodoo

Comment: What type of authentication does the other SQL Server use (SQL or Windows)? Is there a trust relationship setup between the two domains so that you can use the username of the current domain on the other domain (this isn't an issue if you are using SQL login)? Once VPNed you just specify the IP of the other machine and the instance name (IP only if it is a default instance) then the questions to the above questions will specify how you can login.

Comment: might be better asking on serverfault.com

Comment: I have the domain credentials for the machine I will be connecting to.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I posted the same question there as well, should I close this thread or delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the username and password that was provided was removed from their server for unknown reason....
Thanks for the help, appreciated it very much..

Answer (score 1):

Once you're vpn'd in it should be just like local network.  Put the fully qualified server name in the connection dialog in SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. At what point do I put the server name in? at Object Explorere or in the Registered servers? Could you give me step by step explanation - pretend you are talking to a sql-server noob.

Comment: this is not true if you are using windows authentication, it will usually try to send your windows login details, not the vpn login details.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do as normal once vpn'd in, but there are a few catches:

- You may have to use the FQDN. ie `sqlserver.network.local`, not just `sqlserver`
- windows authentication may or may not work, so probably just log in using a sql account, if you have one.